# Using `volatile` has unexpected results

Tags: c++, volatile

I am puzzled by following difference discovered by trying to replicate different bug. This program works as expected:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::string s = "Hi\n";
    std::cout << s;

    auto p = std::make_unique<const char *>(s.c_str());
    std::cout << *(p.get());

    return 0;
}
```

It prints

```
Hi
Hi
```

But adding single `volatile` keyword:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::string s = "Hi\n";
    std::cout << s;

    auto p = std::make_unique<volatile const char *>(s.c_str());
    std::cout << *(p.get());

    return 0;
}
```

makes it print:

```
Hi
1
```

This did not help either:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::string s = "Hi\n";
    std::cout << s;

    auto p = std::make_unique<volatile const char *>(reinterpret_cast<volatile const char *>(s.c_str()));
    std::cout << *(p.get());

    return 0;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Just adding it for no particular reason? My guess is that the formatter thinks this is something other than a C string.

Comment: `std::ostream` has overload for `operator <<` for `const char*` and `bool` (pointer has conversion to `bool`), not for `volatile const char *`

Comment: `volatile` has very few usages. I doubt that your original problem need `volatile`.

Comment: Thank you, @Jarod42, that is really the case as my testing your hypotheses here showed. Original bug may be or not related to using volatile and there is volatile used due to the fact of variable usage in the embedded system. The original bug is more probably related to smart pointer usage.

Comment: please do not add the answer to the question. Instead you should post it as an answer. You can even accept your own answer.

Comment: Beware that you are making a `unique_ptr` to an object you don't own. The `std::string` has unique ownership of the pointed character data and isn't giving up that ownership to the `unique_ptr`. You will get Undefined Behavior due to double `delete` or similar double cleanup at the end of the scope.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Would feel as taking credit for Jarod42 answer.

Comment: @RomanPavelka If they cared about that, they would have posted the comment as an answer instead.

Comment: they gave away their comment. You can do with it whatever you like ;)

Comment: just add a reference to the comment and all is fine. Something like "As Jarod has pointed  out in a comment ...."

Comment: Offtopic: `std::make_unique<const char *>` is already a codesmell?

Comment: Please check [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/2e514e07) (press play button). It shows that different operator overload is selected for both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76672245/using-volatile-has-unexpected-results/76672415#comment135177265_76672245) by [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42):

> `std::ostream` has overload for operator `<<` for `const char*` and `bool` (pointer has conversion to `bool`), not for `volatile const char *`

The difference then can be replicated simply by:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    /*volatile*/ const char * s = "abc\n";
    std::cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Gives `abc` with `volatile` commented out and `1` (without newline) with uncommenting it.

Comment: For reference [`operator <<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) and [`operator <<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2). So in C++23, address would be printed instead of `1` for `volatile` case.

Comment: Nice demo: [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/2e514e07) shows that different operator overload is selected for both cases.